# Slic3r appImage fails to run with `libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so`

Tags: opengl

Slic3r (and possibly other appImages that rely on OpenGL) fail with

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Is there a way to solve or work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because the bundled standard c++ library is outdated (even though I use Ubuntu 16.04.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458071/400257) answer solving the same issue for android studio you need to preload the right c++ library

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' /path/to/Slic3r-Slic3r-1.3.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

If you want to add this to the dash or app grid you can create a `~/.local/share/applications/Slic3r.desktop` with the following contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/icon/Slic3r_128px.png
Name=Slic3r
Terminal=false
Exec=sh -c "LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' /path/to/Slic3r-1.3.0-x86_64.AppImage"
Hidden=false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround not a solution and you have to do it each time unless you know how to make it permanent.  An example is quazix's answer.  But I use Slic3r as part of Repetier Host.

In the user's terminal type:

`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

`cd {path to Repetier appimage eg /home}`

then type

`./{Repetier appimage file}`

Note: do not type the {} just find the correct location of the directory where the appimage is and the appimage file itself in the above two lines.

This removed the error messages for me and allowed me to open the Configuration menu for Slic3r - BUT it crashes Repetier Host if you close the configuration window.

If you also had issues with canberra-gtk try this:

`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-gtk-module:i386`

I think this is because Repetier Host needs 32-bit modules.